# How to start a user mode program from kernel mode in windows

Tags: kernel, windows-kernel, kernel-mode, kmdf, usermode

I have a driver (kernel mode)(KMDF) and i have a user preferences form. i need to start the activity from the driver code and get the preferences.
so how do i start that user mode program from kernel in windows operating system ?

Comment: This looks a bit strange. Why do you need to start preferences form from driver? User-mode program should start by standard way, when user executes it.

Comment: @AlexFarber i want to show a pop up in driver entry and get the result back.

Comment: DriverEntry may be executed at boot time, or before user logon. Anyway, I have never seen such implementation. I think you need to write user-mode program which listens for driver events and shows some UI if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to get a driver to do something in user mode is to have it communicate with a user mode component that can do the work. So you do something like have a user mode service, that opens a channel to the driver, then when the driver needs to do something (e.g., launch a process), it can send a message to the service.

Search osronline for the inverted call model for more information, or look at the FltSendMessage API documentation if you're building a mini-filter.

As other posters have noted, doing this in DriverEntry is probably not going to work since there is likely not even a user session to communicate to.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can't unless you use weird undocumented tricks like APC, that could cause many many incompatibility problems;
just place your application as automatic startup (CurrentVersion\Run for example) and send an IRP to the driver with the data you need to send.